# Split string by one of few delimiters?

Tags: c

I have this

`A > B` , or `A < B` , or `A==B` ,

using the `strtok` I will destroy the data , and my goal is to get some kind of a structure where I can examine :

1. what kind of delimiter I had
2. get access to both sides of it (A and B).

so:

```
if ( > )
do something with A and B
else if (==)
do something with A and B
```

I know it sound simple , but it always comes to be cumbersome .

EDIT:

What i did was this, seems like too long for the task :

```
for (int k=1;k<strlen(p);k++)
{

    char left[4]="" ;
    char right[12]="" ;



    switch(p[k])
    {


        case '>' :
        {
            long num =strstr(p,">") - p ;
            strncpy(left,p,num);
            strncpy(right,p+num+1,strlen(p)-num-1);


            break;
        }



        case '<' :
        {
            long num =strstr(p,"<") - p ;
            strncpy(left,p,num);
            strncpy(right,p+num+1,strlen(p)-num-1);


            break;
        }


        case '=' :

        {
            long num =strstr(p,"=") - p ;
            strncpy(left,p,num);
            strncpy(right,p+num+1,strlen(p)-num-1);


            break;
        }

        case '!' :
        {
            long num =strstr(p,"!") - p ;
            strncpy(left,p,num);
            strncpy(right,p+num+1,strlen(p)-num-1);


            break;
        }

        default :
        {}
    }


}
```

Comment: @mik1904 it will not work with "==", its not a single char.

Comment: Since there may or may not be whitespace separators (or so it seems), mere *pointers* are not enough. You need a `result` struct containing at least a pointer to the start of each token and its length, or, alternatively, duplicate each token into a new string. Code can be very straightforward; what do you have so far?

Comment: @RadLexus I am kind of lost with it, tried few things and never got it to work ( I am not a C guy).  Can you show please any example to loop over, check the signs, and get the left and right string available ?

Comment: Here's an example of `strcspn` from the documentation project: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/1990/strings/10906/strspn-and-strcspn#t=201607301501051078803

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I thought of `strpbrk()` all the solutions have a proble, the `==`.

Comment: `strtok()` destroys the input string and doesn't report on the delimiter that it zapped.  If someone types `1 > 3` with spaces and you break on spaces, then you can use `strtok()`; if you have to analyze `1>3` (no spaces), you can't sensibly use `strtok()` at all.  There are occasions when `strtok()` is 'OK' (but using `strtok_r()` or `strtok_s()` is _always_ a better choice than plain `strtok()`), but it is often not appropriate.  Most likely, this is an example of when it is not appropriate.  Very often, `strpbrk()`, `strcspn()`, `strspn()` will help.

Comment: Writing C code that splits a string into tokens is always going to be somewhat cumbersome. If this is an assignment and you're required to use only C, then it's unavoidable. But parsing arithmetic expressions is something that lots of programs do, and they often do it using `lex` or `flex` and `yacc` or `bison` to generate the C code. Here's a page showing just how simple it can be: http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/flexbison/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generalized procedure:

1. For a given set `delimiters`, use `strstr` to check each if it appears in the input string. As a bonus, my code below allows 'double' entries such as `<` and `<>`; it checks all and use the longest possible.
2. After determining the best delimiter to use, you have a *pointer* to its start. Then you can
3. .. copy everything at its left into a `left` variable;
4. .. copy the delimiter itself into a `delim` variable (for consistency); and
5. .. copy everything to the right of the delimiter into a `right` variable.

Point 4 is 'for consistency' with the other two variables. You could also create an enumeration (`LESS`, `EQUALS`, `MORE`, `NOT_EQUAL` (in my example)) and return that instead, because the set of possibilities is limited to these.

In code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const char *delimiters[] = {
    "<", ">", "==", "<>", NULL
};

int split_string (const char *input, char **dest_left, char **dest_delim, char **dest_right)
{
    int iterator;
    int best_fit_delim;
    char *ptr;

    /* (optionally) clean whitespace at start */
    while (isspace(*input))
        input++;

    /* look for the longest delimiter we can find */
    best_fit_delim = -1;
    iterator = 0;
    while (delimiters[iterator])
    {
        ptr = strstr (input, delimiters[iterator]);
        if (ptr)
        {
            if (best_fit_delim == -1 || strlen(delimiters[iterator]) > strlen(delimiters[best_fit_delim]))
                best_fit_delim = iterator;
        }
        iterator++;
    }

    /* did we find anything? */
    if (best_fit_delim == -1)
        return 0;

    /* reset ptr to this found one */
    ptr = strstr (input, delimiters[best_fit_delim]);

    /* copy left hand side */
    iterator = ptr - input;
    /* clean whitespace at end */
    while (iterator > 0 && isspace(input[iterator-1]))
        iterator--;
    *dest_left = malloc (iterator + 1);
    memcpy (*dest_left, input, iterator);
    (*dest_left)[iterator] = 0;

    /* the delimiter itself */
    *dest_delim = malloc(strlen(delimiters[best_fit_delim])+1);
    strcpy (*dest_delim, delimiters[best_fit_delim]);

    /* update the pointer to point to *end* of delimiter */
    ptr += strlen(delimiters[best_fit_delim]);
    /* skip whitespace at start */
    while (isspace(*ptr))
        ptr++;

    /* copy right hand side */
    *dest_right = malloc (strlen(ptr) + 1);
    strcpy (*dest_right, ptr);

    return 1;
}

int main (void)
{
    char *source_str = "A <> B";
    char *left, *delim, *right;

    if (!split_string (source_str, &left, &delim, &right))
    {
        printf ("invalid input\n");
    } else
    {
        printf ("left: \"%s\"\n", left);
        printf ("delim: \"%s\"\n", delim);
        printf ("right: \"%s\"\n", right);

        free (left);
        free (delim);
        free (right);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

resulting, for `A <> B`, in

```
left: "A"
delim: "<>"
right: "B"
```

The code can be a bit smaller if you only need to check your list of `<`, `==`, and `>`; then you can use `strchr`, for single characters (and if `=` is found, check the next character). You can also forget the `best_fit` length check, as there can be only one that fits.

The code removes whitespace only around the comparison operator. For consistency, you may want to remove all whitespace at the start and end of the input; then, invalid input can be detected by the return `left` or `right` variables having a length of `0` – i.e., they only contain the `0` string terminator. You still need to `free` those zero-length strings.

For fun, you can add `"GT","LT","GE","LE"` to the delimiters and see how it does on strings such as `A GT B`, `ALLEQUAL`, and `FAULTY<MATCH`.

Comment: thanks very much, I will accept that. Can you please see my edit and let me know your opinion about it ?  (is it that bad solution ? )

Comment: @Curnelious: supposed it works (does it, with those `left` and `right` declared inside your `for`-loop?), then it's perfectly alright by my standards. Sure, it can be written less verbose, and perhaps stylistically better as well. If it does the job, consistently and accurate, it's "good enough". It's through exercises such as these you can build up confidence in your C skills.

Answer (score 3):

For simple situations where you just want to parse simple strings consisting of two operands and one operator, no "*expressions*" this might work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    const char *string = "A > B";
    char lho[100];
    char op[3];
    char rho[100];
    if (sscanf(string, "%99[^=><]%2[=><]%99[^=><]", lho, op, rho) == 3) {
        fprintf(stdout, "left hand operand: %s\n", lho);
        fprintf(stdout, "operator: %s\n", op);
        fprintf(stdout, "right hand operand: %s\n", rho);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is by no means the best way to do it, it just shows that you can use it. Also, I didn't think a lot about it, I wrote the code to show you a possible solution. I don't actually like it, and I wouldn't use it

Comment: wow, this seems clever ! :)

Comment: why wouldn't you use it ?

Comment: Because it's not reliable. I can't immediatly think of a case that clearly fails. But I can't trust `sscanf()`. Although as I said, simple cases will work.