# Breaking up a string into a list of tokens using another string as a delimiter?

Tags: c, string, split, string-matching, c-strings

Let's say I have this string:

```
char *myTestString = "Hello AND test AND test2";
```

I want to break this down into the set { `Hello`, `test`, `test2` }, which I can finally iterate over.

Or I have

```
char *myTestString2 = "Hi AND there AND test AND test2";
```

I want to break this down into the set { `Hi`, `there`, `test`, `test2` }, which I can later iterate over.

How do I achieve this using C?

**EDIT**:
Another example is splitting `"Hello there AND test"` should give out set { `Hello there`, `test` }.
For clarification `"AND"` is delimiter here.

Comment: You are looking for `strtok`.

Comment: `strtok` does not support taking another string as delimiter, does it?

Comment: @Zeruno Ignore advices to use strtok. They are wrong advices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675046/split-string-by-one-of-few-delimiters/38675688#38675688

Comment: @Zeruno It looks like more than `"AND"`  is a de-limiter.  The spaces in `"Hello AND test AND test2"` do not appear in ` { Hello, test, test2 }`.  How do you want txt like `" Hello AND test "` and `"Hello (many spaces) AND (tabs, line-feeds, other white space) test"` broken up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char ** split( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char **tokens = malloc( sizeof( char * ) );
    int success = tokens != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        const char *delim = " \t";
        *tokens = NULL;

        for ( size_t n = 1, len = strlen( s2 ); success && *s1; )
        {
            s1 += strspn( s1, delim );

            if ( *s1 )
            {
                const char *p = s1;

                s1 += strcspn( s1, delim );

                if ( strncmp( p, s2, len ) != 0 )
                {
                    char **tmp = realloc( tokens, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char * ) );

                    if ( ( success = tmp != NULL ) )
                    {
                        tokens = tmp;

                        success = ( tokens[n-1] = calloc( 1, s1 - p + 1 ) )  != NULL;
                        strncpy( tokens[n-1], p, s1 - p );
                        tokens[n] = NULL;
                        ++n;
                    }

                    if ( !success )
                    {
                        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) free( tokens[i] );
                        free( tokens );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }       

    return tokens;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s1 = "Hi AND there AND test AND test2";
    const char *s2 = "AND";

    char **tokens = split( s1, s2 );

    if ( tokens != NULL )
    {
        for ( char **p = tokens; *p != NULL; ++p )
        {
            puts( *p );
        }

        char **p = tokens;
        do
        {
            free( *p );
        } while ( *p++ != NULL );

        free( tokens );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hi
there
test
test2
```

The function returns NULL if a memory allocation was not successful. Otherwise it returns a pointer to an array of the element type char * the last element of which is null pointer.

The words in the source string are splited by tabs and spaces. You can change the delimiters as you like.

After your comment to my previous solution it seems you need the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char ** split( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char **tokens = malloc( sizeof( char * ) );
    int success = tokens != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        const char *delim = " \t";
        *tokens = NULL;

        for ( size_t n = 1, len2 = strlen( s2 ); success && *s1; )
        {
            for ( int empty = 1; empty; ) 
            {
                s1 += strspn( s1, delim );
                if ( ( empty = strncmp( s1, s2, len2 ) == 0 ) )
                {
                    s1 += len2;
                }
            }               

            if ( *s1 )
            {
                const char *p = strstr( s1, s2 );

                size_t len1 = p == NULL ? strlen( s1 ) : p - s1;

                char **tmp = realloc( tokens, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char * ) );

                if ( ( success = tmp != NULL ) )
                {
                    tokens = tmp;

                    success = ( tokens[n-1] = calloc( 1, len1 +  1 ) )  != NULL;
                    strncpy( tokens[n-1], s1, len1 );
                    tokens[n] = NULL;
                    ++n;

                    s1 += p == NULL ? len1 : len1 + len2; 
                }

                if ( !success )
                {
                    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) free( tokens[i] );
                    free( tokens );
                }
            }
        }
    }       

    return tokens;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s1 = "Hi there AND test test2";
    const char *s2 = "AND";

    char **tokens = split( s1, s2 );

    if ( tokens != NULL )
    {
        for ( char **p = tokens; *p != NULL; ++p )
        {
            puts( *p );
        }

        char **p = tokens;
        do
        {
            free( *p );
        } while ( *p++ != NULL );

        free( tokens );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hi there 
test test2
```

Maybe you need also to remove trailing blanks of a extracted sub-string that I hope you can do yourself.:).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However it is not only splitting by "AND", but also by " ". "Hello there AND test" should become {Hello there, test} but it seems that this examples gives {Hello, there, test}.

Comment: In my question I thought I was implying splitting by "AND" delimeter, NOT splitting by "AND" and also " ". Sorry about that, you are right I did not explicitly specify delimiter in the question and thought it was implied from question title.

Comment: @Zeruno Well, wait a moment. I will also provide a solution for this case.

Answer (score 3):

When code  does not want to alter the source string, use `strcspn(s, delimet)` to look for initial portion of a `s` **not**  make up of `delimit`.  It returns the offset.

Use `strspn(s, delimet)` to look for initial portion of a `s` made up of `delimit`.  It returns the offset.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how `strspn` would help me achieve my goal?

Comment: @Zeruno "`"AND"` is delimiter here." is a start by not enough,  Please advise how you want spaces near `AND` to be handled.  Examples are not clear enough.  Are only the spaces near/about `"AND"` to be dropped?  How about spaces between `"Hello"` and `"there"` in `""Hello there"`.  Should they all be preserved even if more than one?  What about cases like `" AND AND"`: what should that result look like?

Answer (score 2):

Note: As others mentioned, `strtok()` is no good for string literals, and in this case you should go with Chux's answer ([`strcspn`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/)), but if that's not an issue and you can work with strings stored in arrays, then continue reading. A last resort effort would be to work with a copy of the string literal.

---

First, you have to decide which data structure you'll use for your set (e.g. a simple linked list, where you check before instertion for duplicates).

Then, use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to your string, and if the current token is different than `"AND"` (or any other string to be ignored - you'd have an ignore set of strings as well), then insert it in the set, otherwise, continue to the next token.

---

Here is a basic Complete Minimal Example to get you started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3     // Max size of set
#define LEN 32  // Max length of word - 1

int main ()
{
  char set[N][LEN] = {0};
  char* ignore_str = "AND";
  char str[] ="Hello AND test AND test2";
  char* pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  int i = 0;
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    if(strcmp(pch, ignore_str))
      strcpy(set[i++], pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  printf("My set is: {");
  for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    printf("%s, ", set[j]);
  printf("}\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Splitting string "Hello AND test AND test2" into tokens:
Hello
AND
test
AND
test2
My set is: {Hello, test, test2, }
```

Here, I used an array to represent the set, assuming that the maximum size of the set would be 3. Of course, you could use more dynamic approach instead (e.g. dynamic memory allocated array or list).

Comment: You may not use strtok for string ;literals.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this example. However, I do not fully understand how `strcspn` would change your answer? Also, I do not fully understand why this line is necessary `pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");`?

Comment: You are welcome @Zeruno, I answered because I liked your answer (thus my upvote). The method you mention involves Chux's answer, so maybe it'd be better to comment there (for taxonomy purposes). This line is a leftover, sorry, answer updated. ;)

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the update. "Hello there AND test" should become {Hello there, test} but it seems that this examples gives {Hello, there, test}. I wonder if it has to do with `pch = strtok (NULL, " ");` and how to work around it?

Comment: Sorry I just realized I was not clear that when I was saying using another string as delimeter in question title, in my example I was implying "AND" is delimeter.

Comment: @Zeruno simply change the delimiter then, which is the 2nd parameter of the method, like this `pch = strtok (str," AND");`, and change it in both method's calls.

Comment: It seems that I do not get it to work when I make that change anyway. But other answers have helped me reach my goal, so thank you for showing so much help and depth so early.

Comment: [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xIAjJnoHepR6z1RF) is what I meant by my last comment @Zeruno, but it's OK if you are looking for something different. I am glad you were able to find what you are looking for, awesome! :)

Answer (score 1):

`strstr` can be used to locate the sub-string. Check that the leading and trailing characters are space or trailing terminating zero.
As needed remove whitespace.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ( void) {
    char *myTestString = "   AND SANDY AND Hello there AND AND test AND test2 AND test3    ";
    char *match = "AND";
    char *first = myTestString;
    char *start = myTestString;
    char *find = myTestString;
    int len = strlen ( match);

    while ( isspace ( (unsigned char)*start)) {//skip leading whitespace
        ++start;
        ++first;
    }
    while ( ( find = strstr ( start, match))) {
        if ( find != first) {
            //check for leading and trailing space or terminating zero
            while ( ! (isspace ( (unsigned char)*(find - 1))
            &&  ( isspace ( (unsigned char)*(find + len)) || 0 == *(find + len)))) {
                find = strstr ( find + 1, match);
                if ( ! find) {
                    find = start + strlen ( start);
                    while ( isspace ( (unsigned char)*(find - 1))) {
                        --find;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            int span = (int)(find - start);
            if ( span) {
                printf ( "%.*s\n", span, start);
            }
        }
        start = find + strlen ( match);
        while ( isspace ( (unsigned char)*start)) {//skip trailing whitespace
            ++start;
        }
    }
    if ( *start) {
        int end = strlen ( start) - 1;
        while ( isspace ( (unsigned char)start[end])) {
            --end;//remove trailing whitspace
        }
        printf ("%.*s\n", end + 1, start);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Allocate memory to `char**`, allocate memory and copy each token.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char **freetokens ( char **tokens);
void showtokens ( char **tokens);
char **addtoken ( char **tokens, int *count, char *text, int size);

int main ( void) {
    char *myTestString = "   AND SANDY AND Hello there test AND AND test2 AND test3   ";
    char *match = "AND";
    char *first = myTestString;
    char *start = myTestString;
    char *find = myTestString;
    char **tokens = NULL;
    int items = 0;
    int len = strlen ( match);

    while ( isspace ( (unsigned char)*start)) {//skip leading whitespace
        ++start;
        ++first;
    }
    while ( ( find = strstr ( start, match))) {
        if ( find != first) {
            //check for leading and trailing space or terminating zero
            while ( ! (isspace ( (unsigned char)*(find - 1))
            &&  ( isspace ( (unsigned char)*(find + len)) || 0 == *(find + len)))) {
                find = strstr ( find + 1, match);
                if ( ! find) {
                    find = start + strlen ( start);
                    while ( isspace ( (unsigned char)*(find - 1))) {
                        --find;//remove trailing whitespace
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            int span = (int)(find - start);
            if ( span) {
                tokens = addtoken ( tokens, &items, start, span);
            }
        }
        start = find + strlen ( match);
        while ( isspace ( (unsigned char)*start)) {//skip trailing whitespace
            ++start;
        }
    }
    if ( *start) {
        int end = strlen ( start);
        while ( isspace ( (unsigned char)start[end - 1])) {
            --end;
        }
        tokens = addtoken ( tokens, &items, start, end);
    }

    showtokens ( tokens);

    tokens = freetokens ( tokens);

    return 0;
}

char **addtoken ( char **tokens, int *count, char *text, int size) {
    char **temp = NULL;
    if ( NULL == ( temp = realloc ( tokens, sizeof *tokens * ( *count + 2)))) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "problem realloc tokens\n");
        return tokens;
    }
    tokens = temp;
    tokens[*count + 1] = NULL;//sentinel
    if ( NULL == ( tokens[*count] = malloc ( size + 1))) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "problem realloc tokens[]\n");
        return tokens;
    }
    memmove ( tokens[*count], text, size);
    tokens[*count][size] = 0;//terminate
    ++*count;

    return tokens;
}

char **freetokens ( char **tokens) {
    int each = 0;
    while ( tokens && tokens[each]) {
        free ( tokens[each]);
        ++each;
    }
    free ( tokens);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer and I appreciate the extra effort invested in handling whitespace.

Comment: `char` arguments to `isspace()` must be cast as `(unsigned char)` to avoid undefined behavior for negative characters on platforms where `char` is signed by default.

Answer (score 0):

`strstr()` is the tool you are looking for. It can locate a string inside another string.

Here is a simple solution with these extra specifications:

- the return value is an array of (n+1) entries, the last one being a null pointer.
- the separator string can appear anywhere, including inside a word.
- substrings are trimmed: initial and trailing white space is removed
- substrings are allocated with `strndup()` which is standardized in POSIX.
- the separator string must have a length of at least 1

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strdup_trim(const char *s, size_t n) {
    while (n > 0 && isspace((unsigned char)*s)) {
        s++;
        n--;
    }
    while (n > 0 && isspace((unsigned char)s[n - 1])) {
        n--;
    }
    return strndup(s, n);
}

char **split(const char *str, const char *sep) {
    size_t i, n, sep_len = strlen(sep);
    char **a;
    const char *p, *p0;

    if (sep_len == 0)
        return NULL;
    for (n = 0, p = str; (p = strstr(p, sep)) != NULL; n++, p += sep_len)
        continue;
    a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * (n + 2));
    if (a == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 0, p = str; (p = strstr(p0 = p, sep)) != NULL; i++, p += sep_len) {
        a[i] = strdup_trim(p0, p - p0);
    }
    a[i++] = strdup_trim(p0, strlen(p0));
    a[i] = NULL;
    return a;
}

void free_split(char **a) {
    if (a) {
        for (size_t i = 0; a[i]; i++)
            free(a[i]);
        free(a);
    }
}

void test(const char *str, const char *sep) {
    char **a = split(str, sep);
    printf("split('%s', '%s') -> {", str, sep);
    for (size_t i = 0; a[i]; i++)
        printf("%s '%s'", &","[!i], a[i]);
    printf(" }\n");
    free_split(a);
}

int main() {
    test("Hello AND test AND test2", "AND");
    test("Hi AND there AND test AND test2", "AND");
    test("Hello there AND test", "AND");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
split('Hello AND test AND test2', 'AND') -> { 'Hello', 'test', 'test2' }
split('Hi AND there AND test AND test2', 'AND') -> { 'Hi', 'there', 'test', 'test2' }
split('Hello there AND test', 'AND') -> { 'Hello there', 'test' }
```